# Mirroring on-premise SQL Server to AWS EC2 SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring, high-availability

Trying to mirror an on-premise SQL Server instance to EC2 instance, but not much information is available on this topic. The closest one I managed to find is: [Implement SQL Server High Availability and Disaster Recovery on Amazon EC2 - Part 4](https://mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5181/implement-sql-server-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-on-amazon-ec2--part-4/)

Has any one done this? If so is there any documentation available?

My intention is to make the EC2 as a backup for the HA in case my on-premise DB crashes.

Please note that this is not for AWS RDS, nor EC2 SQL Server to EC2 SQL Server; but on-premise SQL Server to AWS EC2 SQL Server.

The DB version is not a constraint, it can be SQL Server 2017 too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but yes I have this working. Ended up using mirroring due to company policy between SQL 2016 AWS and on premise SQL 2016 running on Vmware.

Found this link very helpful.

https://tecadmin.net/setup-database-mirroring-sql-server/

I know not exactly what you were looking for but thought might help.